# Regarding convergence of a series related to Mangoldt $\Lambda$ function used in PNT.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, absolute-convergence

While self studying analytic proof of Prime Number Theorem from Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory , I couldn't think about a deduction in theorem contour integral representation of $\psi_1(x) $ / ($x^2$) .

> My only doubt in this theorem is how Apostol writes $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Lambda(n) / n^c $ to be absolutely convergent if $c>1$.

Can someone please tell how this is true?

Comment: $|\Lambda(n)|\le\log n$, right? and $\sum (\log n)/n^c$ is absolutely convergent for $c>1$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the Dirichlet series in question is equal to $-\zeta'(c)/\zeta(c)$, i.e. the negative of the logarithmic derivative of $\zeta(c)$. As $\zeta(s)$ converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$, the series does too.